# Use \pgfmathresult in siunitx

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I try to do some calculation and then want to use the result in a `siunitx` `qty`.
However, this fails and I don't know why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, siunitx}

\newcommand{\scale}[1]{\pgfmathparse{#1/3.13-0.3}\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}

Without siunitx: \(\scale{5}\)

With siunitx: \(\qty{\scale{5}}{\celsius}\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use a non-expandable command inside the number part of `siunitx`.*  The entire reason `\pgfmathparse` sets `\pgfmathresult` is because `\pgfmathparse` is not expandable. You could use a wrapper around `\qty` that does the assignment then only passes the result, but with `siunitx` v3 you can use an expression directly

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xfp} % pre-2022-06-01 LaTeX
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\scale}[1]{\fpeval{#1/3.13-0.3}}

\begin{document}

Without siunitx: \(\scale{5}\)

With siunitx: \(\qty[evaluate-expression]{\scale{5}}{\celsius}\)
\end{document}
```

(You don't *need* `\fpeval` for this to work with `siunitx`, but you do for it work outside of `\qty`.)

---

- In LuaTeX one can use `\immediateassignment`, but I will ignore that here!

Comment: Unrelated. If someone runs this example on Overleaf, beware `\fpeval` is not available in old LaTeX format (aparently before 2022-06-01 according to [xfp](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xfp.pdf)) and will get an error about "Undefined control sequence". One needs to add `xfp` package in order for the example to work.

Comment: @Celdor I've addressed that

Comment: The same holds for `\num`.